# Difference between today and a date python

Tags: python, time, arithmetic-expressions

I have a pandas dataframe in which a column is in this format:

```
0         1983-02-07
1         1989-10-07
2         1969-10-28
3         1967-02-25
4         1982-07-21
             ...    
328970    1995-06-09
328971    1999-01-11
328972    1962-04-01
328973    1996-05-19
328974    1994-03-03
Name: Nascita - Data, Length: 328975, dtype: object
```

what I'd like to do is something like

```
df['datecolumn']-datetime.now()
```

Comment: ok, what is stopping you from doing so?

Comment: They don't have the same format and I don't know how to convert the first into a datetime format

Comment: See the line in my answer `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
data = ["1983-02-07", 
"1989-10-07", 
"1969-10-28", 
"1967-02-25", 
"1982-07-21"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date"])
print(df)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#df["Difference"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x-datetime.now())

# Alternate code
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
df["Difference"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: relativedelta(datetime.now(), x).years)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Date
0  1983-02-07
1  1989-10-07
2  1969-10-28
3  1967-02-25
4  1982-07-21

Date                   Difference
0 1983-02-07 -13409 days +06:41:00.418879
1 1989-10-07 -10975 days +06:41:00.418728
2 1969-10-28 -18259 days +06:41:00.418671
3 1967-02-25 -19235 days +06:41:00.418630
4 1982-07-21 -13610 days +06:41:00.418591
```

**OUTPUT ALTERNATE CODE:**

```
Date
0  1983-02-07
1  1989-10-07
2  1969-10-28
3  1967-02-25
4  1982-07-21

Date  Difference
0 1983-02-07          36
1 1989-10-07          30
2 1969-10-28          49
3 1967-02-25          52
4 1982-07-21          37
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have the difference just in years?

Comment: Look over [this](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/06/how-use-datetime.html) link, and see if it helps you manipulate the datetime objects better

Comment: See the changes above. The key is in the `df["Difference"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: <some function using x>)`

Comment: NP. If it helped, please select an answer and/or upvote. It helps the site maintain its curation.